# How to render json data inside textarea with custom result value

Tags: reactjs

My question is based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076276/how-to-render-pretty-json-data-inside-text-area-react-js), I want to render json data inside textarea with custom result value.

Code:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const data = [
  {
    name: "peter",
    location: "boston"
  },
  {
    name: "john",
    location: "florida"
  }
]

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea value={data.map(e => JSON.stringify(e).replace(/{|}/g, '')).join('\n')} rows='3' cols='30' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Result :

[image]

How if i expected result just json value and add a string 'at' between first and second value like image below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two properties of each object inside the `map` using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like so:

```jsx
const text = data
  .map(item => `${item.name} at ${item.location}`)
  .join('\n')
```

Here's a working example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jzGOZQ)